# How can I use multiple -S values with aapt without using <add-resource>?

Tags: android, aapt

I am trying to build R.java by using aapt from the command line. I am specifying multiple `-S` directories because I have multiple `res` directories. I am building by using:

```
aapt package \
  -M AndroidManifest.xml \
  -m -J gen \
  -S src/com/example/res \
  -S src/com/example/ui/res
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

```
src/com/example/ui/res/values/strings.xml:2: error: Resource at app1_name appears in overlay but not in the base package; use <add-resource> to add.
```

Currently, `src/com/example/ui/res/values/strings.xml` contains the following:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app1_name">MyAppName</string>
</resources>
```

I would prefer not to have to change this to:

```
<resources>
    <add-resource type="string" name="app1_name">MyAppName</add-resource>
</resources>
```

(This was suggested on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-porting/bYfeLEjERjg, though it does not even seem to solve my problem.)

Am I misguided in my expectation of how the `-S` argument should work?

The only workaround I can think of is to symlink all of my `-S` directories as subdirectories of the root `res` directory and to specify `res` as the only `-S` directory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the solution is to use the `--auto-add-overlay` flag. I discovered this by running the default Ant build script with `-v` for verbose mode.